# JPA org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA . I am getting the following error when running through multiple transactions.

For example add

1. Add Event 21
2. Add Event 22
3. Delete 22
4. Delete 21

Now when I go in to add a new event it indicates that a different object is already associated with this session.

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.domain.Event#22]
```

I think I understand what is going on but am not sure how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried flushing the session before recreating the deleted entity?

```
session.flush();
```

Comment: I tried to flush and that didn't work. Trying a merge also didn't address the issue.

Comment: I tried clearing it before I started the transaction. This actually worked so thanks a lot for that. Problem is I am getting stale exceptions and out of index and that nature after this fix. I think I have 3 tasks 1) Delete 2) Add 3) Update a task. I think if I can fix the delete part it could solve the issue but still stuck.